# Get all the times between two dates at given intervalls

Tags: vb.net, time, intervals

I need to get the specified times with given intervals from the last 7 days. Currently I am using this code:

```
 If startdate = Nothing Then
        startdate = Date.Now.AddDays(-7)
    End If
    If enddate = Nothing Then
        enddate = Date.Now
    End If

    Dim curstartdate As DateTime = startdate
    Dim curenddate As New DateTime


    While curenddate < DateTime.Now
        Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
            Case "every 15 minutes"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddMinutes(15)
            Case "every 30 minutes"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddMinutes(30)
            Case "every hour"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(1)
            Case "every 2 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(2)
            Case "every 3 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(3)
            Case "every 6 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(6)
            Case "every 12 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(12)
            Case "every 24 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(24)
        End Select

     ***DO SOME FANCY STUFF***
     curstartdate = curenddate
   end while
```

It is working, gut if i Run this ad for example 9:12 with an interval of 15 minutes i get all the hours of the last days having minutes 12,27,42,57... and if the code is slow (that happens due to external factors) i get a last time block going from for example 9:12 to 9:27 even if it is still 9:12.

I would need it to return the values referred to the 00 hour (midnight of 7 days ago). so 00,15,30,45.. and the very last time should be left away (so no time blocks that go beyond now)

How could I do this?

---

*** EDIT: I did it like this, is it a good way to solve the problem? ***

```
 If startdate = Nothing Then          
        startdate = New DateTime(Now.AddDays(-7).Year, Now.AddDays(-7).Month, Now.AddDays(-7).Day, 0, 0, 0)
    End If
    If enddate = Nothing Then
        enddate = Date.Now
    End If

    Dim curstartdate As DateTime = startdate
    Dim curenddate As New DateTime


    While curenddate < DateTime.Now
        Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
            Case "every 15 minutes"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddMinutes(15)
            Case "every 30 minutes"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddMinutes(30)
            Case "every hour"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(1)
            Case "every 2 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(2)
            Case "every 3 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(3)
            Case "every 6 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(6)
            Case "every 12 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(12)
            Case "every 24 hours"
                curenddate = curstartdate.AddHours(24)
        End Select


          ***DO SOME FANCY STUFF***

  curstartdate = curenddate
end while
```

Comment: Yup.  That's a decent solution.

Comment: ok, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly cleaner option;

```
startdate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=netframework-4.7.2